# Flag comments render embedded links but they are not clickable

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderator-tools, flag-queue

#### Problem:

If a flagging user puts a (markdown) link in a flag comment, eg:

```
This answer is a duplicate of [another answer](some url)
```

when viewed by a moderator in the flag queue, the *another answer* link is  visually rendered correctly as a clickable link, but it is not clickable because the *entire* flag comment is itself a link to take moderator action of decline/helpful etc, which masks the inner link.

Inspecting the HTML shows that the anchor tag is actually there.

Putting a link to another post seems reasonable and helpful to me.

#### Request:

Make the moderator action link active only on the non-anchor-tag (if any) parts of the flag comment, allowing any embedded anchor tags to be functional.

There is an edge case when the entire comment is a link, which would leave no room for the moderator action link, but I wouldn't bother worrying about it as  I have never seen in the wild and it only prevents flag-specific actions.

#### Work around:

As commenters have pointed out, the work around is to right-click on the embedded link and "open in new tab". I have confirmed that this works in mobile (iPhone/Chrome) too.

Comment: I have always just right-clicked "open in a new window" so I could see both the flagged item and the linked item. Not the best solution, but it's a workaround until this gets fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure about comment flags, but in post flags, you can get to the link destination by right-clicking and choosing "Open in new Tab/Window", like bluefeet said.

Comment: @Daniel OK. Question edited to reflect this work around.

Comment: I just left-clicked, and two things happened: a) the flag handling dialog popped up (briefly), and b) I was taken to the link destination. Doesn't it take you to the link destination if you left-click?

Comment: @dan it didn't using chrome in Windows 7